# How can I avoid spiraling streamlines in matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, magpylib

I am attempting to use `matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot` for displaying magnetic fields generated using magpylib. I adapted the following from one of their examples in order to display complete lines with a controlled spacing but I have problems with the fact that some magnetic lines which are theoretically closed on themselves do not in practice close on themselves but instead spiral, probably due to numerical instabilities or approximations, from matplotlib, from `magpylib` or from both. Is there a way to prevent unbroken streamlines to spiral or, even better, to tell matplotlib to close the streamlines on themselves when possible?

Code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import magpylib as magpy

# Create a Matplotlib figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# Create an observer grid in the xz-symmetry plane
ts = np.linspace(-5,5,200)
grid = np.array([[(x,0,z) for x in ts] for z in ts]) # slow Python loop

# Compute the B-field of a cube magnet on the grid
cube = magpy.magnet.Cuboid(magnetization=(0, 0, -1000), dimension=(2, 2, 2))
B = cube.getB(grid)
x, y, u, v = grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], B[:, :, 0], B[:, :, 2],

# Mask for breaking the streamlines
u[98:102, 80:120] = np.nan
v[98:102, 80:120] = np.nan

top_seed_points = np.array([np.linspace(-1.0, +1.0, 21), np.ones(21)])[:,:-3]
bottom_seed_points = np.array([np.linspace(-1.0, +1.0, 21), -np.ones(21)])[:,3:]
left_seed_points = np.array([-np.ones(4), 1-(0.05+(np.linspace(0, 1, 4, endpoint=False))**2)])[:,:3]
right_seed_points = np.array([np.ones(4), (0.05+(np.linspace(0, 1, 4, endpoint=False))**2-1)])[:,:3]
seed_points = np.concatenate((top_seed_points, bottom_seed_points, left_seed_points, right_seed_points[:, :3]), axis=1)

# Display the B-field with streamplot using log10-scaled
# color function and linewidth
splt = ax.streamplot(
    x, y, u, v,
    start_points=seed_points.T,
    broken_streamlines=False,
)
ticks = np.array([3,10,30,100,300])

# Outline magnet boundary
ax.plot([1, 1, -1, -1, 1], [1, -1, -1, 1, 1], "k-", lw=2)
ax.set_xlim([-5, 5])
ax.set_ylim([-5, 5])

# Figure styling
ax.set(
    xlabel="x-position (mm)",
    ylabel="z-position (mm)",
)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]

I tried to break the spiraling using masks but some streamlines managed to make it through the masked region (which I would consider as a bug) and to spiral anyway.

Note: the result is the same if I do the masking in this way:

```py
# Mask for breaking the streamlines
mask = np.zeros(u.shape, dtype=bool)
mask[98:102, 80:120] = True
u = np.ma.array(u, mask=mask)
v = np.ma.array(v, mask=mask)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, [with the help of Jody Klymak, Member of Matplotlib Developers](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/27261), I discovered an alternate solution for displaying streamlines without using streamplot. The idea is to [build a stream function from the vector field](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1784352/1221716) and to draw its contours. The stream function psi is built by integrating any path starting from a fixed point as:

psi(x,y) = integral (on C from origin to (x,y)) of u.dy - v.dx

i.e., dpsi/dx = -v and dpsi/dy = u. The result does not depend on C if div(u, v) = 0, which does not work with any field but does for planar magnetic fields. For the above example (with some adjustments):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import magpylib as magpy

# Create a Matplotlib figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# Create an observer grid in the xz-symmetry plane
ts = -5+10*(np.arange(201)+0.5)/201
grid = np.array([[(x,0,z) for x in ts] for z in ts]) # slow Python loop

# Compute the B-field of a cube magnet on the grid
cube = magpy.magnet.Cuboid(magnetization=(0, 0, -1000), dimension=(2, 2, 2))
B = cube.getB(grid)
x, y, u, v = grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], B[:, :, 0], B[:, :, 2],

# Build the stream function and plot its isolines
dx, dy = x[0,1]-x[0,0], y[1,0]-y[0,0]
psi = np.cumsum(u,axis=0)*dy-np.cumsum(v[0:1,:],axis=1)*dx
psi -= np.min(psi)
levels = np.linspace(psi[101,81], psi[101,119], 31)
plt.contour(x, y, psi, levels=levels, colors='blue', linewidths=1.0)

# Outline magnet boundary
ax.plot([1, 1, -1, -1, 1], [1, -1, -1, 1, 1], "k-", lw=2)
ax.set_xlim([-5, 5])
ax.set_ylim([-5, 5])

# Figure styling
ax.set(
    xlabel="x-position (mm)",
    ylabel="z-position (mm)",
)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After having looked at the `streamplot`source code, I got the explanation of why the streamlines makes it through the masked region by some kind of "tunnel effect": the integration process jumps from locations to locations by a step size which may happen to be bigger than the width of the masked region. The scale of the step size is not directly accessible a as parameter to `streamplot()` but it can be indirectly controlled via the `density` parameter (which is a bit weird as this parameter is not supposed to have any effect when `streamplot` is used with start points). Just adding `density=60` to the streamplot parameters in the code above fixed it:
[image]
This also happened to fix the fact that the streamlines did not extend to the boundary of the masked region. Reducing the step size by increasing the value of the density parameter is likely to increase the accuracy of the streamlines though at the cost of an increase in computation time.

This remains a workaround however and in order to get the complete and closed streamlines, I have to use two masks and to superimpose the streamlines obtained using both of them, which is not very convenient, and adjusting the size and locations of the masks for that is a bit cumbersome. Unfortunately, it seems that with the current state of the code, there is no simple way to do it directly.